# HTML video muted stop my background music on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, video

I have an issue when trying to play systematically an array of videos contained in an array.

When I load the link and I .play() it, the background music (Spotify or whatever else) stops.

On a laptop it works fine, no errors on the console.

The videos are without audio track and the object is muted.

Here is my code:

```
<video id="videoplayer" autoplay loop playsinline muted title="" poster=""> 
<source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
//code
video.pause()
video.setAttribute("src",videos[c]);
video.load();
video.play();
//code
</script>
```

Any help to solve this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's the Application issue. Your browser automatically stops the background music as a sound is played in it. Its similar to other applications do. And it should be stopped otherwise the user will listen to two sounds.

Comment: Hi Rajat thanks for answering. My videos are all without audio track. My goal is to play them without sound, letting the user to listen a background music, using for example Spotify. Any idea how can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this all depends on your mobile browser. You cannot change its settings like this way.